# Center search field using Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

As most people seem to have this problem I've gone through a lot of answers, but none have worked for me yet.

I'm looking to center the search box and search button

```
<div class="hero-unit">
<div class="main-top-container">
        <%= simple_form_for(@search, :url => search_properties_path, :method => :post, :html=> { class: 'input-height', id: 'main_search_form' }) do |f| %>
            <div class="row main-top-search-row">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <h1 class="col-sm-12 search-title">Find magic</h1>
                        <div class="main-top-searchfield col-sm-4">
                            <%= f.input :location, :required => false, label: false, input_html: {id: "search_query", class: "form-control typeahead"}, :placeholder => "Search..." %>
                        </div>
                        <%= button_tag( :class => "btn btn-primary btn-custom-red col-md-1", :id => "search_button") do %>
                            Search
                        <% end %>
                      <!--  <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-1">
                            <a class="how-it-works" href="/faq">How It works</a>
                        </div> -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div> 
        <% end %>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried to use CSS on each element, but for some reason it does not allow me to align center.....

Comment: Hello, can you create jsfiddle? It's easier for us to find solution.

Comment: @Aleksandar is right right. We cannot help much when we do not have access to a problematic example

Comment: @Aleksandar What do you mean by jsfiddle?

Comment: @RubyMax http://jsfiddle.net is website where you create full examples, combining JavaScript, CSS and HTML. We can review your code, edit your code and give you solution where you can test code right away. Just create code on jsfiddle, click `Run` to test and `Save` to save your fiddle. Then paste link to your fiddle here.

Comment: Ok, bear with me! Thanks :)

Comment: For some reason it's not showing a live result of the code, I believe since I've built the code on Ruby? http://jsfiddle.net/kd4s6ub9/

Comment: @Aleksandar forgot your tag in my last comment.

Comment: Yes,its because of ruby code,just rewrite your code to plain html,it's not difficult

Comment: You don't need to write it in html, just view your code in a browser and copy the source for that section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### DEMO: https://jsbin.com/piwefi/

[image]

**CSS:**

```
html,
body {
    height: 100% /* not necessary if you have a fixed height on the feature area */
}
/* ------ featurette */
.featurette {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30%; /* set a pixel height and then remove the body,html height */
    vertical-align: middle;
    background: #555;
    color: #fff;
}
.featurette-inner {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.featurette .search {
    padding: 3%;
    max-width: 980px; /*max width of search*/
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.no-margin-top {
    margin-top: 0
}


/* ------ form-control-lg */
.form-control-lg {
    min-height: 46px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: normal;
}


/* ------ disjointed form group custom */
.featurette .search.has-button .btn {
    margin-top: 5px;
    width: 100%;
}
@media (min-width:480px) { 
    .featurette .search.has-button .form-group {
        position: relative;
        padding-right: 99px; /*space for button*/
    }
    .featurette .search.has-button .btn {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        width: auto;
        margin: 0;
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<!-- example 1 -->

<div class="featurette">
   <div class="featurette-inner text-center">
      <form role="form" class="search">
         <h3 class="no-margin-top h1">Search Me.</h3>
         <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
            <input type="search" placeholder="search" class="form-control">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button">Search</button>
            </span>
         </div>
         <!-- /input-group -->
      </form>
      <!-- /.max-width on this form -->
      
   </div>
   <!-- /.featurette-inner (display:table-cell) -->
   
</div>
<!-- /.featurette (display:table) -->

<hr>

<!-- example 2 -->
<div class="featurette">
   <div class="featurette-inner text-center">
      <form role="form" class="search has-button">
         <h3 class="no-margin-top h1">Search Me.</h3>
         <div class="form-group">
            <input type="search" placeholder="search" class="form-control form-control-lg">
            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-warning" type="button">Search</button>
         </div>
         <!-- /form-group -->
      </form>
      <!-- /.max-width on this form -->
      
   </div>
   <!-- /.featurette-inner (display:table-cell) -->
   
</div>
<!-- /.featurette (display:table) -->
```

Comment: Christina thanks for taking the time to do this! One quick issue I have is I'm extremely new to coding and this code throws up a whole new set of questions. I'm guessing this is the best approach, but how do I link in the relevant parts of my code to it? You have clearly taken the time to comment in what needs to be where, but it makes little sense to me sadly. Once again, thanks for your help!!! :)

Comment: This is html and css just like Bootstrap, which is html and css. I can't tell you anything more, add the classes like you would in Ruby and incorporate the CSS in your Sass file, at the end and then re-compile. Open another question with Ruby tag if you have trouble